# Would I use mb_substr string to do this?

Tags: php, arrays, multibyte

I am looking for a way to delete only those elements in an array that start with a vowel. so adam would be deleted, edward would be deleted and so on and so forth. My friend told me that to do this I would use [mb_substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) and associated functions.

But I am lost as to how this would look or even why I would use multi byte string manipulation to this. Can some one point me in the right direction please on how you would remove all elements starting with a vowel from an array

**Because I have confused some people**

If the array looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    array('title' => 'apples'),
    array('title' => 'jack')
)
```

then apples will be removed, while jack will not because it does not start with a vowel.

Comment: Are you working with multibyte strings (UTF-8 maybe)? There's nothing in your question that indicates what kind of data you're dealing with.

Comment: `foreach($array as $index => $element) { $first = mb_substr($element, 0, 1, $encoding); if(in_array($first, $vowels)) { unset($array[$index]); } }`. Defining a list of characters that constitute "vowels" across all supported alphabets is up to you.

Comment: @JohnFlatness sorry I was working with just a regular array of key=>value, how ever my friend said that for what I want to do i should use multi byte string manipulation functions

Comment: @DCoder what is encoding? or $encoding? where is that defined? I assume $vowels would be what ever I defined as a vowel? or set of vowels? would that be an array? a concatenated string?

Comment: Could I understand that you want to remove the first word of every array's key's value?

Comment: @sємsєм No if the array is array('title' => 'song', 'title' => 'apples'); then apples will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

What language / set of vowels you expect?  If it is English and `aeiou` then you don't need multibyte function here, case closed. But let's make it more interesting, say we expect Polish input that has 9 vowels: `aeiouyąęó`.

Now the problem is with encoding. It is 2013 and everybody should use `utf8`, but as we all know, some people just want to watch world burn and still use `iso-8859-2` or even worse `windows-1250`. If we know it, that's great, we can move on - if it is `utf8` than yes, multibyte function will be required, for the remaining two it is not needed.

However, if data comes from various sources and you can not determine it's encoding, but stil have to correctly respond to all cases... Well, then I feel sorry for you, since it's hard to determine real encoding. But you will surely need mb_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array_filter(
    $array, 
    function($x) { 
        return !stristr('aeiou', $x['title'][0]); 
    }
);
```

`array_filter` returns a new array whose elements are all the ones for which the function is true. `$x` is the elements of the array being filtered, and `$x['title'][0]` is the first character of the value of its title element.  `stristr` performs a case-insensitive search of the first argument, so it checks whether that first character is in the string of vowels.  If it's found, `stristr()` returns the position, otherwise it returns false; `!` inverts the truth value of this, so the function returns true if the first character is *not* a vowel.

Comment: I have no idea what this does sorry.

Comment: Will explain shortly (once I debug it)

Comment: In some languages, vowels can be multibyte

Comment: @MichelFeldheim I don't know multilingual way to test for vowels. Feel free to post an answer that addresses this issue. I suspect that any application that cares whether the first letter is a vowel will be inherently language-specific (e.g. in English, putting "a" or "an" before the word).

Answer (score -1):

Only reason you would want to use `mb_*` is when you are working with strings that aren't ASCII (such as "ふーばー"). But in your case since you are only looking for vowels, it would be pointless.

```
// go over each element in the array
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    //check if the first character of the title is a vowel (ignore case, ie 'a' or 'A')
    if (stristr("aeiou", $value['title'][0]))
    {
        // remove it from the array
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `$value['title'][0]` that may break unknown possibly multibyte string, and `mb_stristr` on known, non-multibyte set of vowels.

Comment: What string did you use that would break it?

Comment: Of course it will work on test cases, since broken multibyte character will not be a vowel. I'm saying that your usage is wrong and pointless.